# Segurança ao inserir dados no banco de dados

Tags: php, segurança

Seguinte, tenho um formulário de contato numa página, e gostaria de que ele só funcionasse dentro da página propriamente dita, e não que terceiros consigam enviar requisições POST por programas maliciosos ou ETC, algo como uma "trava" para que naquela página fosse gerado algum código de verificação, como posso fazer isso?

Estrutura simples:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="teste" />
</form>
```

Comment: Acho que entendi entendi a idéia, mas como seria isso na prática?

Comment: pesquise no google "php captcha"

Comment: No ASP.NET MVC existe um conceito de "anti-forgery token" que é Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF). Pesquisei no google "anti-forgery token PHP" eu achei isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287903/how-to-properly-add-csrf-token-using-php isso é uma especie de  hash que você adiciona na sessão na hora de entregar o formulário e valida no post. Procure por esses conceitos que vai conseguir.

Comment: @Miguel isso ai que você disse é bem falho. Dá pra submeter o "YOO". Basta o cara analisar o fonte HTML do browser que vai descobrir isso.

Comment: @DanielOmine o captcha hoje em dia dá pra quebrar também. Têm scripts que interpretam captchas, mas já dificulta bem. O ideal é aplicar o conceito CSRF

Comment: Foi apenas um comentário e não uma solução definitiva. Além do mais, captcha mal feito sempre foi violável. Há diferentes formas de implementar um captcha. E CSRF não o substitui, inclusive é muito fácil de burlar. O problema do captcha é que torna a UX mais burocrática. Ninguém gosta de preencher aqueles códigos, chatos e muitas vezes ilegíveis, durante um login ou um cadastro. Mas ainda assim é o mais seguro quando bem empregado. Um dos mais inteligentes e simples é algo assim, usado atualmente numa das páginas administrativas do facebook: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gqhtO.jpg

Comment: Falando um pouco mais já que tocou no assunto e para não deixar muito vago o que comentei, experimente essa library que simula navegação como se fosse um browser: http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html É tudo em PHP. Com essa library consegue acessar uma página e submeter formulários com uma sessão válida. Apenas teste e veja como é simples burlar o CSRF. Não é a toa que existe captcha. Mas como citei acima, deve-se considerar o modelo de negócio do site. Num site técnico pode ser um captcha mais complexo. Num site como o facebook tem que ser bem amigável e obviamente, seguro.

Comment: Amigos, implementei um pequeno exemplo numa aplicação-teste e consegui burlar ela com um script em python que pegava o valor do formulário e adcionava ao request, como proceder agora? vi algo relacionado à json tokens, mas não li muito sobre, sugestões?